# SetKeyboardLayout() analog for GTK?

Tags: linux, gtk, porting

I have to port one GUI application  from windows to linux/GTK.  On windows I can define input language in text control using SetKeyboardLayout() function.  So, I'm  looking for   Get/SetKeyboardLayout() replacement code for GTK.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to change the input language?

Comment: On linux there's [setxkbmap](http://ftp.x.org/pub/X11R6.7.0/doc/setxkbmap.1.html)

Comment: @Joel that is [a global solution to a local problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx). The reason for my question above your comment is that I'm pretty sure what the person wants to do is misguided (indeed, it may very well be misguided *in the original Windows program*, especially since I see no such `SetKeyboardLayout()` function in MSDN)

Comment: Is not global, because only affects the current logged user, once logoff returns to the old state. Oh, you are right, no SetKeyboardLayout API o.O

Comment: Ok. My mistake. The  correst function name is HKL WINAPI LoadKeyboardLayout(
  _In_  LPCTSTR pwszKLID,
  _In_  UINT Flags
);

Comment: But the problem is still the same.  On windows version of  the program( I have to port ) user can select input language in combobox and input text in the edit control below in selected language.  On GTK version - user have to do something additional to change keyboard mapping. On windows I can change  keyboard layout  in any event handler( on combobox selection change, get/lost control focus etc. )   How to implement such behavior in GTK?